# How to turn featurized text back to actual text in ML.NET (for chatbot)?

Tags: c#, nlp, bots, ml.net

I am trying to create an FAQ bot with ML.NET (cannot use QNA Maker). I want to compare the questions in the FAQ KB to an input and then return the most relevant answer. Most FAQ bots I found online worked like this: featurize the FAQ questions, featurize the input, do a cosine similarity, and then return the most relevant answer. I don't really understand Microsoft's featurization but I can't even test it because I can't find how to relate the feature vector to the original text.

This is what I have so far (in Main):

```
mlContext = new MLContext(seed: 0);
IDataView dataview = mlContext.Data.LoadFromTextFile<SampleData>("Data/training_data.tsv", hasHeader: true);
var textPipeline = mlContext.Transforms.Text.FeaturizeText("Features", "Question");
var textTransformer = textPipeline.Fit(dataview);
var predictionEngine = mlContext.Model.CreatePredictionEngine<SampleData, TransformedTextData>(textTransformer);
SampleData sampleData = new SampleData()
    {
        Question = "Setting Up Data Exchange" //would be changed to user input
    };
var prediction = predictionEngine.Predict(sampleData);
Console.WriteLine($"Number of Features: {prediction.Features.Length}");
Console.Write("Features: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        Console.Write($"{prediction.Features[i]:F4}  ");
```

SampleData class:

```
public class SampleData
{
        [LoadColumn(0)]
        public string Question { get; set; }

        [LoadColumn(1)]
        public string Answer { get; set; }
}

public class TransformedTextData : SampleData
{
        public float[] Features { get; set; }
}
```

It returns the feature vector but almost all of the values are zero so hopefully that's normal, but I just don't know how I can turn this into readable output. Also I don't understand why I can't just featurize and model just the FAQ text, why do I need a sample question, I feel like that's inefficient and probably I'm not going about it right. Thanks for any help!

Comment: What learner are you using ? `mlContext.Transforms.Text.FeaturizeText` sounds like a pipeline transform and not a trainer. example trainers i know `Context.Clustering.Trainers.KMeans`, `Context.Regression.Trainers.FastTree`, `Context.Regression.Trainers.Sdca`. All their namespace specify `Trainers`

Comment: @Franck I don't think I need a trainer, my plan is just to featurize the FAQ questions, featurize the input, do a cosine similarity, and then return the most relevant answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think ML.NET can actually do what I wanted, turns out just modifying [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/tutorials/github-issue-classification) to what I wanted worked well enough.

Basically they can't just featurize a section of text but the text must be featurized in context to being trained.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to also keep the original text, setting the `OutputTokensColumnName` parameter, in the `TextFeaturizingEstimator.Options`.

See [this sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.textcatalog.featurizetext?view=ml-dotnet#Microsoft_ML_TextCatalog_FeaturizeText_Microsoft_ML_TransformsCatalog_TextTransforms_System_String_Microsoft_ML_Transforms_Text_TextFeaturizingEstimator_Options_System_String___) for more.

```
 var options = new TextFeaturizingEstimator.Options()
            {
                // Also output tokenized words
                OutputTokensColumnName = "OutputTokens"                    
            };
            var textPipeline = mlContext.Transforms.Text.FeaturizeText("Features", options, "Text");
```